# rails in_place_edit: how do I pass an authenticity token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, token, in-place-edit, authenticity

I am trying to get in place editing working but I am running into this error:

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)

I understand that rails now wants to protect against forgery and that I need to pass a form authenticity token but I am not clear on how to do this with the in_place_edit plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.  I put the instructions [here](http://blog.ennuyer.net/?p=299).  Take a look at the part on patching in_place_edit.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a <strike>complete</strike> tested answer, but I took a look at the [plugin code](http://svn.rubyonrails.org/rails//plugins/in_place_editing/lib/in_place_macros_helper.rb), and it looks like you could use the `:with` option to tack the authenticity token onto the end of the request parameters.  Something along the lines of:

```
in_place_editor("my_element", :with => "form.serialize() + '&authenticity_token=#{form_authenticity_token}';")
```

(I have not tested the above code).